# sometimes the citation works while sometimes it's not

Tags: citing

I'm using the template of Elsevier, I got a interesting problem. Sometimes the citations worked but other time they didn't and show me a question mark like "[?]".

My file looks like the flowing:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
    \interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
    \usepackage{array}
    \newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}p{#1}}
```

And then the body is:

```
\journal{Vehicular Communications}
    \begin{document}
    text goes here...
\cite{ieee2010ieee,etsi2010302}...\cite{resendes2010vehicle}
    ...
    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
    \bibliography{elsdoc}
    \end{document}
```

My bib file is elsdoc.bib

```
@article{ieee2010ieee,
      title="\protect{IEEE Standard for Information
Technology--Telecommunications and information exchange between
systems--Local and metropolitan area networks--Specific
requirements--Part 11: Wireless LAN Medium Access Control (MAC) and
Physical Layer (PHY) specifications Amendment 6: Wireless Access in
Vehicular Environments}",
      author="\protect{IEEE 802.11 Working Group} and others",
      journal="IEEE Std",
      volume="802",
      number="11",
      year="2010"
    }
@article{etsi2010302,
      title={\protect{302 665 v1. 1.1: Intelligent transport systems
(ITS)}},
      author={ETSI, EN},
      journal={Communications architecture},
      year={2010}
    }
@inproceedings{resendes2010vehicle,
      title={Vehicle-to-vehicle and safety pilot},
      author={Resendes, R},
      booktitle={Proceedings of US Department of Transportation Safety
Workshop},
      year={2010}
    }
```

The full template is https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid I'm not able to reproduce the issue you describe, using solely the code you've provided, converting the code into a compilable example, and running a full latex-bibtex-latex-latex compilation cycle. Please do tell us more about how you compile your document. E.g., do you run latex-bibtex-latex-latex every time you add additional `\cite` instructions? Please advise.

Comment: Incidentally, none of the three `\protect` statements are needed. Who taught you how to define BibTeX entries in this manner?

Comment: I use makefile to to this job. and when I delete some words(\cite{} is not included) , the problem disapeared.

Comment: Without knowing what's actually done by makefile, it's not possible to provide further advice, is it?

Comment: yes! Thank you for your time and answers, I'll find it out what happened exactly and then put the problem here. :)